# Create a single value validation relative to another field in the same table Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, many-to-many

I have an intermediate table with game_id, categories_id and rating fields.

I need the rating value to be unique for each category in the table itself.

That is, there cannot be two records with rating 3 for categories_id 13. At the Database level, I have already defined that constraint correctly:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('categories_game', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('rating')->default(null)->nullable();
            $table->unique(array('categories_id', 'rating'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('categories_game', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('rating');
        });
    }
```

If I try to enter the same rating value for the same category directly in DB, the exception is thrown:

**ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry '13-3' for key**,
which means it's working, but I don't know how to validate it.

I have tried something like this:

`'rating_arcade' => 'unique:categories_game,rating,categories_id'.$request->rating_arcade[0]`

but it doesn't work, i'm stuck.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try this like the [document](https://laravel.io/forum/11-03-2015-laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns-for-unique-relations) says.

Comment: Thanks @BhaumikPandhi but it doesn't me, it doesn't describe how it works. Thanks again